# Insert Statement is showing error "Incorrect syntax near ="

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to insert values of checkboxlist into transaction table but it's showing me error that

> InCorrect Syntax Near '='.

```
if (cblAmenity.SelectedIndex >= 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cblAmenity.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (cblAmenity.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            ds = obj.sel("Select MAX(PropertyId) AS PrptId from tblPropertyMaster");
            string a = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PrptId"].ToString();
            string nature = "Sell";
            obj.insert("insert into tblAmenityToPropertyTransaction Values (AmenityName=" + i + " , PropertyId=" + a + " , Nature='" + nature + "')");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Thats not the correct syntax

Comment: What is the type of `obj`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INSERT INTO in sql server doesn't work in that way

```
 INSERT INTO table VALUES(value1, value2, value3)
```

not

```
 INSERT INTO table VALUES(field=value, field1=value1....)
```

However, apart from this, try to use always a parameterized query.
In your wrong syntax you use a string concatenation to build your command, but this is an open door to [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and infinte source of problems when the values concatenated in your string contains invalid characters (for example a single quote inside a string)

Comment: Ohh sosorry sir, even though i've done this so many time as per your syntax i just forget syntax of insert statement because of frustration :(

Comment: The curious thing is that a syntax like that is supported by MySql

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong INSERT statement syntax,

Example Insert statement

```
insert into table1(col1, col2)
values (val1,val2);
```

Your statement should be

```
"insert into tblAmenityToPropertyTransaction (AmenityName,PropertyId, Nature)
Values (" + i + " ," + a + " , '" + nature + "')"
```

And please use [parameterized SQL statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

`Insert into tblAmenityToPropertyTransaction (AmenityName,PropertyId, Nature)
Values (" + i + " ," + a + " , '" + nature + "')"`